# Lightswitch Cannot read property 'read' of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I was working with a friend on a Lightswitch HTML Client and he has it stored on git through Visual Studio Online. So he added me to his team and I downloaded the server copy to my local machine.  Well now, everytime I try to access data from those table entities it gives me an error of "Cannot read property 'read' of undefined'".

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's trying to tell you that the Entity (with the property 'read') is undefined (or null).  I'd suggest you publish a copy of the database locally, update your connection string to work locally, and add some test data to the database and re-test.

Also, this can occur if you don't call a 'get' on the entity first.  (Some queries are deferred until you call get)

Comment: Kris how would I update my connection string to work locally?